# MVC - Get Drop Down list Selected value in Window.Open

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my MVC View I have a DropDownList in a form

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ddlAbb"
        , new List<SelectListItem>(){
            new SelectListItem { Selected = true, Text = "All", Value = "-1"},
            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "Some", Value = "1"},
            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "Not Some", Value = "0"}
        }
        , new { @id = "ddlAbb", @class = "form-control", @onchange = "$(this).closest('form').submit();" })
```

and for me is easy to get its value on submit.

But in the same page i have another button not in the form:

```
<input type="button" value="Report" onclick="window.open('@Url.Action("GetPdf", "PrintList", new { listId = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"], ddlAbb = [selectedValue]})')" />
```

As you can see, I need to get the DDL selected value for use it as parameter in a windows.open function.

Is there any way to do this in a MVC View?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, shame for me.
I was only looking the problem from a wrong view.
I simply needed to create a function to get the selected value of the DDL and open the new windows. Then I need to call this function `onclick` instead of `window.open`.